# Access other (not mine) google accounts public calendars in android

Tags: android, calendar

here I am once again asking what might be something obvious for some of you, but that troubled me for a while.

I'm trying to make an app for a friend, he wants this app to be able to access all the events of public calendars owned by a list of google users (so not owned by the user logged in the device).
Once gathered these events, they should be viewed in some kind of list. Only viewed, not modified.

The question is, **is it possible to access other accounts public calendars? And If so, how can I do that?** I've tried to check the documentation but I couldn't find anything :/

**EDIT**: these are the only "useful" thing I've found on internet, the [Calendar API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), an [Android Quickstart with calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android), and a [link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) to what looks like something close to what I want but done manually, through the web interface

I've managed to get the REST request set to the server to get MY events. It looks like this:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=<API_key>
```

I see there is written *me* after *users* so I've tried to put my friend's email to try and get his public calendar, but the server replied with **404 Not Found**.

**END EDIT**

Thanks!

Comment: At least show what you have done. Even if it is just research...

Comment: Why did you downvote my question? 
What should I show you? The google search I've done? The fact that there is nobody else asking for this thing in stakoverflow? I mean, I really don't know what should I link :/
The only thing I could do is to link the documentation, but I don't think that would be useful since there's written nothing about it.

Comment: 1) I did not downvote your question. 2) When I red it the first time I understood your question, but did not know what you have tried / searched. This way we know better where you stand. 3) There are a lot of low quality questions here on SO. The better your question, the better change you have for an answer. 4) Downvoting is used as "bad question, you should feel bad" thing. I don't like it, and in this case I don't think its a bad question.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad then. Anyway, do you have any clue how to do such a thing?

Comment: Maybe, I think it is possible. But have not done so myself. Will try to get back on this later.

Comment: Ok, solution found. I'll post the guide to how to do it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the solution, at least one that works for me. If anyone has a better one feel free to share.

I've made a really basic "how to", here is the link to the [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HS0KFCMHQIN2VoVDMyWXBRMzQ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your how-to, I am currently working on this same problem. Your help got me part of the way there, but how do I get an authorisation token? I found a way to do it but it seems to require permission from the app user. Is there a way to do get a token without user intervention? Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it has been useful to someone else. I need to check a few things, right now I don't have a PC but I'll try tomorrow morning and will let you know

Comment: @Marein So, here is the thing, as long as the google account that you want to get the token from is registered on the device, you don't need to ask the user anything.
Let's say I want to get the token from this google account: _account@gmail.com_. And let's say this account is registered on the device I'm using, what I need to do is this:
`mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(),     Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
mCredential.setSelectedAccountName("account@gmail.com");`

Is this what you were looking for?